# Use a field other than the category field to set marker-width in CartoDB's Torque Category

Tags: carto, torque

I have rabies data that contains a date, animal type and county.  The centroid of the county polygon was used to generate a geometric point, the date used for Torque's Time Column, and the animal type for Torque's Category column.  I would like to use the count of each type of animal for a given date county combination to set the marker-width using CartoCSS.

It seems that for Torque the value of a field is not accessible to CartoCSS as [field] although you can access the numeric value of your category using [value].  Is there a way to pass the value of another field to Torque either using sql to generate count(animal type) grouped by animal type, time and county or by having Torque directly calculate the number of category records?

Comment: hope this [link](https://github.com/CartoDB/torque/blob/master/examples/navy_leaflet.html#L21) could be helpful.